# Weird behaviour using writeFrame in Opencv

Tags: python, video, opencv

I have a small problem using the video creation capability of OpenCV.

For the same images, I get a weird output depending on the output size I want.

Here is an example of the results I can get.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wm8VjyfdyA&feature=youtu.be

I tried with several different sets of images, and on different computers. 
It seems to run fine on Windows, and I have problems with the Opencv that ships in Ubuntu packages (current 2.3.1-7).

As the problem is not reproductible on my windows, I guess its was either fixed in the 2.4 or specific to Linux.

Here is a (python) test code that highlight the problem :

```
import os
import cv

in_dir = "../data/inputs/sample-test"
out = "output.avi"


# loading images, create Guys and store it into guys
frameSize = (652, 498)
#frameSize = (453, 325)
fourcc = cv.CV_FOURCC('F', 'M', 'P', '4')
my_video = cv.CreateVideoWriter(out, 
                              fourcc, 
                              15, 
                              frameSize,
                              1)

for root, _, files in os.walk(in_dir):
    for a_file in files:
        guy_source = os.path.join(in_dir, a_file)
        print guy_source
        image = cv.LoadImage(guy_source)

        small_im = cv.CreateImage(frameSize, 
                                  image.depth ,
                                  image.nChannels)        
        cv.Resize(image, small_im, cv.CV_INTER_LINEAR)
        cv.WriteFrame(my_video, small_im)

print "Finished !"
```

My concern is that depending on the output size, the video is fine (652, 498 is ok for example).
The behaviour is the same whatever codec I use.

If not a fix, I´d like some more information about the reason for this bug. 
As I want to ship for Ubuntu, I´d better use their packaging system and keep the 2.3 for some time.

So I would like to know how I can wisely solve the problem, by choosing educated sizes.

Any information is welcome

Thx !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem in video coding. As you can see, the image is shifted with a small amount to left each row.

As you may know, the image is saved as a long row of chars: BGRBGRBGR.... 
It is also defined by its width and height, and by step - the distance, in bytes, between two consecutive rows. A naive supposition is that the step is 3(channels)*width. But in addition, for memory alignment reasons, the image rows are padded with some extra bits, in order to make the step value a multiple of 4 (usually) or 16. The reason is that hardware codec acceleration works with aligned data - 32bit architectures read 32bits at once, and for SIMD processing, aligned data is loaded faster.

So the image will be represented as

```
BGRBGR00
BGRBGR00
```

Now, if a codec does not know of this padding, it will read the width of the image as 2, and will interpret the data as follows:

```
BGRBGR
00BGRB
0000BG // note the extra padding
```

To make sure you do not experience this issue, you should select image width in such a way that the step value (channels*width) is a multiple of four. All of the standard resolutions have this property, and this is one of the reasons they were selected so:

```
640x480
1024x768
etc
```

Comment: +1 - `All of the standard resolutions have this property, and this is one of the reasons they were selected so`. I have thought why this kind of weird numbers, it is really new to me.

Comment: Thx for your answer ! I did know about the encoding and noticed the regular padding added in my video, but never made the actual relation with SIMD instructions and common resolutions. I'll try to find the closest couple that gets this relation then. Thanks !